# Firebase console isn't loading in any browser

Tags: firebase, get, firebase-console

I am trying to open Firebase console but it doesn't load. I tried to disable all extensions of the browsers but that doesn't help. I tried also to open it in incognito tab but it also doesn't work. When I pressed f12 on my browser to open the browser's console I found this error :

> GET [https://www.gstatic.com/*/fireconsole/*/js/k=fireconsole.fb.en_US.rOiX_jdO2H4.O/am=A7gwJH0esmZ27nWBIiA/rt=j/d=1/rs=AON9PuleFwUnRbsV1IuOvw-wleC3Zu9UmQ/m=console_main](https://www.gstatic.com/_/fireconsole/_/js/k=fireconsole.fb.en_US.rOiX_jdO2H4.O/am=A7gwJH0esmZ27nWBIiA/rt=j/d=1/rs=AON9PuleFwUnRbsV1IuOvw-wleC3Zu9UmQ/m=console_main) net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Comment: I just opened the Firebase console landing page and the Firestore tab on Chrome and Safari, and the console loads fine for me. You might want to try on a different network, to see if its an issue with connectivity/firewall/proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open fire base in incognito tab

Answer (score 1):

If this is specific to your computer, then it's probably an issue with your ISP.

Try changing your DNS settings. If you are on a MAC OS, go to systems Preferences -->Network --> Advanced --> DNS --> Then add either the OPEN DNS or Google DNS.

**Open DNS is 208.67.220.220 and 208.67.222.222**

**Google DNS is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.**

On Windows, Control Panel-> Network and Sharing Center -> Click on your primary connection or Local Area Connection under Active Networks -> Properties -> Highlight Internet Protocol Version -> Properties -> Then change the DNS as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by turning off the windows firewall

Answer (score 0):

**I resolve by this way,**

In the Extension tab > top right corner developer mode> make enable

Thanks...